# Request with morphs table seems invalid as relations are not set?

Tags: laravel, eloquent

In laravel 10 app I have a table with morphs field defined :

```
public function up(): void
{
    Schema::create('reactions', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->id();
        $table->foreignId('user_id')->nullable()->references('id')->on('users')->onDelete('CASCADE');

        $table->morphs('model');
        $table->unsignedTinyInteger('action');

        $table->timestamp('created_at')->useCurrent();

        $table->unique(['model_type', 'model_id', 'user_id', 'action']);
    });
}
```

with relative model app/Models/Reaction.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\BelongsTo;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\MorphTo;

class Reaction extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected $table = 'reactions';
    public $timestamps = false;

    protected $fillable = ['model_id', 'model_type', 'user_id', 'action'];

    public function scopeGetByModelType($query, string $modelType = null)
    {
        if ( ! empty($modelType)) {
            $query->where($this->table . '.model_type', $modelType);
        }

        return $query;
    }

    public function scopeGetByAction($query, int $action = null)
    {
        if ( ! empty($action)) {
            $query->where($this->table . '.action', $action);
        }

        return $query;
    }
    public function scopeGetByUserId($query, int $userId = null)
    {
        if ( ! empty($userId)) {
            $query->where($this->table . '.user_id', $userId);
        }

        return $query;
    }
    public function user(): BelongsTo
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(User::class);
    }

    public function scopeGetByCreatedAt($query, $filterCreatedAt= null, string $sign= null)
    {
        if (!empty($filterCreatedAt)) {
            if (!empty($sign)) {
                if (in_array($sign, ['=', '<', '>', '<=', '>=', '!-', '<>'])) {
                    $query->whereRaw($this->table . '.created_at ' . $sign . ' ?', [$filterCreatedAt]);
                }
            } else {
                $query->where($this->table.'.created_at', $filterCreatedAt);
            }
        }
        return $query;
    }

    public function model(): MorphTo
    {
        return $this->morphTo();
    }

}
```

Now 'reactions' table have only rows on news table with model app/Models/News.php:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use App\Enums\NewsPublishedEnum;
use Config;
use DB;
use Spatie\Sluggable\HasSlug;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Relations\HasMany;

class News extends Model
{
    use HasSlug;
    use Notifiable;

    protected $primaryKey = 'id';
    public $timestamps = false;
    protected $table = 'news';

    protected $newsImagePropsArray = [];    protected $img_filename_max_length = 100;

    protected static $uploads_news_dir = 'news/-news-';
    protected $fillable
        = [
            'id',
            'news_category_id',
            'title',
            'slug',
            'content',
            'content_shortly',
            'creator_id',
            'is_homepage',
            'is_top',
            'published',
            'image',
            'source_type',
            'source_url',
            'youtube_key',
            'updated_at'
        ];





    public function creator()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo('App\Models\User', 'creator_id');
    }



    public function scopeGetByPublished($query, NewsPublishedEnum $published = null)
    {
        if ( ! isset($published->value) or strlen($published->value) == 0) {
            return $query;
        }

        return $query->where(with(new News)->getTable() . '.published', $published->value);
    }


    public function scopeGetBySlug($query, $slug = null)
    {
        if (empty($slug)) {
            return $query;
        }

        return $query->where(with(new News)->getTable() . '.slug', $slug);
    }

}
```

This model has no any relation to Reaction model and I do not know which relation must be added in it ?

I made an request :

```
$this->filterDateFrom = Carbon::now()->addDays(-7)->startOfDay()->format($this->dateFormat);
$this->filterDateTill = Carbon::now()->addDays(+1)->endOfDay();
$filterMinSummaryReactionLimit = 2;
$reactionTb = (new Reaction)->getTable();

$this->ratedReactions = Reaction
    ::getByCreatedAt($this->filterDateFrom, '>=')
    ->getByCreatedAt($this->filterDateTill, '<')
    ->getByModelType(News::class)
    ->leftJoin('news', 'news.id', '=', $reactionTb . '.model_id')

    ->whereHas('model', function ($news) {
        $news->where('published', NewsPublishedEnum::PUBLISHED);
    })
    ->groupBy('model_id')
    ->groupBy('action')

    ->having('reaction_count', '>=' , (int)$filterMinSummaryReactionLimit)
    ->orderBy('reaction_count', 'desc')
    ->select( $reactionTb . '.model_id',
        $reactionTb . '.action',
        DB::raw('count('. $reactionTb.'.id) as reaction_count') )
    ->get()->toArray();
```

Which is rendered with next sql :

```
   SELECT `reactions`.`model_id`, `reactions`.`action`, count(reactions.id)     AS reaction_count
    FROM `reactions`
    LEFT JOIN `news` on `news`.`id` = `reactions`.`model_id`
    WHERE reactions.created_at >= '2024-03-08 00:00:00'     AND reactions.created_at < '2024-03-16 23:59:59'     AND
    `reactions`.`model_type` = 'App\\Models\\News'     AND ((`reactions`.`model_type` = 'App\\Models\\News'     AND
    EXISTS (  SELECT *
    FROM `news`
    WHERE `reactions`.`model_id` = `news`.`id`     AND `published` = '1')))
    GROUP BY `model_id`, `action`
  HAVING `reaction_count` >= 0
    ORDER BY `reaction_count` desc
```

Now with only 1 morph table "news" it returns valid data, but I am afraid that with several morph table data would be wrong.
What have I to change ?